# Select pixelformat H264 for webcam in Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, webcam

I am using a webcam with Chrome Browser on Linux that supports full hd resolution. The camera supports H.264 encoding to provide acceptable frame rates on full hd over USB 2.0.

When selecting the camera in Chrome, and the website requests a resolution of 1920x1080, the camera delivers that resolution, but still using YUV format (can be checked by `v4l-ctl` tool for example). This causes a framerate below 10 fps, limited by USB 2.0 transfer rate.

How can I force Chrome to use the apropriate format (H264) of the camera?

Comment: Some additional info would help: Do the linux drivers of that camera support the h.264 streaming? Does it work in another software (i.e. grabbing the stream with ffmpeg)? Which linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Yes, it works with any software that provides the interface to select the pixelformat (like ffmpeg or vlc). I think Chrome just defaults to YUV as this is the first format in the list of possible formats?

Comment: I am not sure if that works, but you could try some of the hidden settings in chrome (chrome://flags). The settings for hardware video encoding for webRTC may help. Otherwise, you could try to grab the video via some other software and pipe it through to chrome.

Comment: Actually on some other machine, I first used VLC to set the camera to H.264 encoding and then started a Chromium browser capture. However, the setting is not kept. BUT on this machine Chromium used MJPEG by default (the third format listed), which is not perfect but much better. I now wonder if this is a Chromium vs. Chrome issue, or caused by running VLC before.

Comment: VLC can stream video over a network. You could try to stream the video from the camera using VLC (and h264 encoding) and then grab it from localhost with chrome.

Comment: Also, you could try to add video format selection as a feature request to [the chromium issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).